# SQL server trimming all entries in a field to the same size

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, truncate

I have a field in SQL server that has a bunch of different sized strings in it. I need to cut down or truncate all of these strings so that they are 16 characters long, but I do not want to do this using a `select` statement.

I know that I can use:

```
insert into some_table (column1, column2, ...)
    select left(column1, 16), column2, ...
    from some_other_table
```

then insert the newly shortened strings back into the 1st table, but I do not want to do this, it is too round about.

Is there a command I can use to just cut the strings down to 16 characters in the table I am already in? I tried to mess around with the `TRIM` command, but that would only remove the spaces off of the end or beginning

Comment: update ... set column = left(column, 16)?

Comment: have you thought of using UPDATE some_Table SET COL1 = LEFT(COL1, 16) ...

Comment: no i havent, thank you ill try that

Comment: @SteveFord that worked, post that as the answer and ill mark it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Update statement:

```
UPDATE some_Table SET COL1 = LEFT(COL1, 16) ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of `Column1` from whatever it is now to **varchar(16)** (or nvarchar) would do it, but you could lose data if any value is longer than 16 characters.